# When testing a React component, is there any way to directly call its non-lifecycle methods?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using Jest, and I have some component like:

```
var TestClass = react.createClass({
  foo: function() {
    return "test";
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div />;
  }
});
```

And I want to write a unit test specifically for `TestClass`' `foo` method.

I saw that [Call a React component method from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612598/call-a-react-component-method-from-outside) suggested this should be possible - simply render the component in the test and call it:

```
describe("TestClass", function() { 
    it("should access internal methods", function() { 
    var test = <TestClass />

    expect(test.foo()).toBeTruthy()
  }
});
```

From that question's answer I would expect this test to pass, but instead:

> test.foo is not a function

Have I misunderstood that answer?

In general I would prefer to be able to test non-lifecycle methods in this manner - it would give better granularity, but if this is not possible, is there a sane alternative?

For example how might one test a method passed as props to a component's child without this ability?

Comment: I would guess that the variable `test` in your test is not an instance of the class but just the rendered component (or whatever the `.renderIntoDocument` returns).

Comment: That's what I get for slapping together a contrived example for stack overflow! Will edit

Comment: `expect(TestClass.prototype.foo()).toBeTruthy();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `renderIntoDocument`:

```
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

...

const test = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <TestClass />
);
expect(test.foo()).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: document is not defined... This would only work in the browser. :\

Comment: Correct - we are using renderIntoDocument from ReactTestUtils after all :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using enzyme instead of ReactTestUtils, and you are using enzyme's mount renderer, then you can call .instance() on the ReactWrapper to retrieve the ReactComponent.

```
var test = mount(
  <TestClass />
);

expect(test.instance().foo()).toBeTruthy();
```