# ReactJS - How to use method from other component of other file?

Tags: reactjs, components, render

I want to use method ***getMuseumsList()*** from *MuseumData class* in *MuseumTable class*.

The both class is in **different file**.

MuseumData.js

```
 class MuseumData extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    getMuseumList() {
        return ("TEST");
    }



}
```

MuseumTable.js

```
class MuseumTable extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {

    }

}
```

Comment: I react, component can share methods if they have parent-child relationship. Else you can't.

Comment: Is the files by chance parent-child? If yes, you can simply pass the method from parent using props

Comment: Ideally you should have a third file from which you should export that function, import that file in both the react class files and use it there.

Comment: so many answers available on SO for the same ques, so instead of asking new ques first try those, if that doesn't help then include the link of those ques and ask a new one, check this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612598/call-a-react-component-method-from-outside

Comment: Thanks everyone....