# SwaggerUI 3.x: How can I set parameter value programmatically?

Tags: swagger-ui

I'm using SwaggerUI 3.21.0 and would like to set a query parameter value programmatically. When you press the button, the calculated value is set as the parameter. The parameter itself is defined in the openapi.yaml and a textbox is created by SwaggerUI. First I tried `$(element).val(value)` with jQuery, and the value appeared in the textbox, however it didn't affect the url SwaggerUI requests. Next I noticed that SwaggerUI uses React under the hood, and tried `FindReact` and `setState` from the question below. However, this also didn't affect the url. It seems like that SwaggerUI keeps the values somewhere internally. Does anyone have any idea?

[React - getting a component from a DOM element for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321742/react-getting-a-component-from-a-dom-element-for-debugging/39165137#39165137)

Comment: You may have better luck asking this question in the Swagger UI repository https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Answer (score 1):

The missing was to trigger event for React. This answer worked charmly!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012210/5209556

Comment: Finally! After two hours of debugging, your answer worked for me. Thank you!

As @Grin said at the link, the problem is:
`Setter .value= is not working as we wanted because React library overrides the input value setter.`