# Acessing ReactJS Props/States via Greasemonkey?

Tags: reactjs, greasemonkey

Is it possible to access reactjs props and states via greasemonkey? I can see the props and states in the react console, but as far as I have found, I have not been able to utilize greasemonkey to interact with it.

Comment: Why not try finding out how react console gets the variables?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155044/how-do-you-inspect-a-react-elements-props-state-in-the-console

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321742/react-getting-a-component-from-a-dom-element-for-debugging

Comment: If you're trying to do this in 2023, I think the way to go is via https://stackoverflow.com/a/74240138/620699