# How to Get React Element Props from HTML Element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can inspect a component's props with the React developer tools. Is it possible to get the component's props from its corresponding HTML element from the console without using the developer tools?

The solution would be something like this:

```js
const someElement = document.querySelector('.some-element')
getElementReactProps(someElement)
```

I tried to inspect the HTML element's properties `__reactFiber$at69yqn7c1k` and `__reactProps$at69yqn7c1k` but couldn't find any of its props that I see in the React developer tools.

I have also found other stack overflow threads but none of them worked. ([React - getting a component from a DOM element for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321742/react-getting-a-component-from-a-dom-element-for-debugging), [React - get React component from a child DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462679/react-get-react-component-from-a-child-dom-element), [How do you inspect a react element's props & state in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155044/how-do-you-inspect-a-react-elements-props-state-in-the-console))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

React *does* seem to store the correct properties in some parent elements, but not in child elements.
The code below works by walking down the path from the given parent to the target child in the react prop tree, after tracing it from the DOM tree. I've only tested it with a single app but I believe it works with all elements created by React 17+.

```js
function getReactProps(parent: Element, target: Element): any {
    const keyof_ReactProps = Object.keys(parent).find(k => k.startsWith("__reactProps$"));
    const symof_ReactFragment = Symbol.for("react.fragment");

    //Find the path from target to parent
    let path = [];
    let elem = target;
    while (elem !== parent) {
        let index = 0;
        for (let sibling = elem; sibling != null;) {
            if (sibling[keyof_ReactProps]) index++;
            sibling = sibling.previousElementSibling;
        }
        path.push({ child: elem, index });
        elem = elem.parentElement;
    }
    //Walk down the path to find the react state props
    let state = elem[keyof_ReactProps];
    for (let i = path.length - 1; i >= 0 && state != null; i--) {
        //Find the target child state index
        let childStateIndex = 0, childElemIndex = 0;
        while (childStateIndex < state.children.length) {
            let childState = state.children[childStateIndex];
            if (childState instanceof Object) {
                //Fragment children are inlined in the parent DOM element
                let isFragment = childState.type === symof_ReactFragment && childState.props.children.length;
                childElemIndex += isFragment ? childState.props.children.length : 1;
                if (childElemIndex === path[i].index) break;
            }
            childStateIndex++;
        }
        let childState = state.children[childStateIndex] ?? (childStateIndex === 0 ? state.children : null);
        state = childState?.props;
        elem = path[i].child;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Example usage:

```js
let itemRow = document.querySelectorAll("#item-row")[2];
let menuBtn = itemRow.querySelector("#more-button");
let props = getReactProps(itemRow, menuBtn);
//This may also work:
let props = getReactProps(menuBtn.parentElement, menuBtn);
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I'm using your code on Selenium and it's working very well :)